# I have a button that doesnt respond. After I turn off screen and turn it back on it responds. Other button works fine

Tags: java, android

this is my main

```
package com.example.student.poker;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.example.student.poker.variables.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        playeronestack = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playeronechip);
        playertwostack = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.playertwochip);
        playeronecheckbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playeronecheck);
        playertwocheckbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playertwocheck);
        playeronebetbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playeronebet);
        playertwobetbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playertwobet);
        playeronefoldbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playeronefold);
        playertwobutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playertwofold);
        playeronebettext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.playeronespecifybet);
        playertwobettext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.playertwospecifybet);
        playeronefirstcard = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playeronefirst);
        playertwofirstcard = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playertwofirst);
        playeronesecondcard = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playeroneSecond);
        playertwosecondcard = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playertwosecond);
        firstflopcard = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.firstflop);
        secondflopcard = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.secondflop);
        thirdflopcard = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.thirdflop);
        fourthflopcard = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fourthflop);
        fifthflopcard = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fifthflop);
        dealerbuttonone = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dealerbuttonone);
        dealerbuttontwo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dealerbuttonone);
        pottext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.potsize);
        startbutton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startbutton);


        if(turn == 2){
            preflop.preflopturn();
        }
        if(turn == 7){
            startbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    turn = 1;
                }
            });
        }
        if(turn == 1) {
            dealing.deal();
        }

    }
}
```

Turn starts out at 7 and when I hit, it it doesn't respond. But after I close the screen and open it again, it responds.
Also I have all the variables in a different class. Turn 1 is supposed to deal the cards and at the start of turn 2 it displays the cards. In the `dealing.deal` it sets turn to turn 2. It works but you have to close the screen and turn it on for it to proceed.

Comment: Where id you declare the turn and what is the default value?

Comment: i declared it in a different java class with all my variables. it starts at 7

Comment: btw i have 2 xml files which are activity_main.xml and activity_main.xml(land). not sure which it is using ;-;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John,

Your current code will only run once, as the method is only called **once** in the whole lifecycle of the app, onCreate. What you need to do is the following:

1. Where you've defined your button in XML, add this code:

   android:onClick="YOUR_METHOD_NAME"
2. Create the method in the class with the following syntax:

   ```
   public void YOUR_METHOD_NAME (View v) {
   if (turn == 1) {

   }
   else if (turn == 2) {

   }
   else if (turn == 7) {

   }
   /*Add a fallback clause in case none of the     conditions are met as a safeguard*/
   }
   ```
3. Reformat your code to make it more readable - delegate different code to different functions!!

**EDIT**
replace everything in the method you created with only the following code

```
turn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
startbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        if(turn == 2) preflop.preflopturn();
        if(turn == 7) turn = 1;
        if(turn == 1) dealing.deal();
    }
});
```

ps: there is a better way to do this , create a method with a View argument like :

```
     public void buttonStart(View v)
     {
         // place your if , else and anything else here
     }
```

now on your layout.xml here you have the Button start

```
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/startbutton"
      ......
      ......
      aandroid:onClick="buttonStart">
```

this way you do NOT need create a object of your Button in your java code, and it looks nice too.

Comment: startbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        if(turn == 2) preflop.preflopturn();
        if(turn == 7) turn = 1;
        if(turn == 1) dealing.deal();
    }
});

Comment: I want the start button to only initiate the game. I dont want it to be able to move the game forward. The only problem I'm having is that the startbutton works but only after I turn off the phone and back on. the button that closes the screen

Comment: thanks for the tip on creating buttons with if statements tho :)

Comment: that is many ways that you can do , you make a boolean flag like boolean goHead = false; and set it true when you want , than use this boolean in your if() or you can make the button invisible using  android:visibility="invisible" and in your java when you want to show the button you can create a a object of your button and use bt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); if yo use a flag your button will be show but will be deactivate until you decide to activate it , if you decide make it invisible the button will only show when you want to show it , for game i like the second approach.

Comment: ;-;. I just want the button to do what its supposed to do. Atm its just doing nothing until u turn the screen off and back on. It shows what it did afterwards. everything else is fine

Comment: The problem is we do not have you code complete , whatever you place inside onCreate will be called once only , and it will be called again only if you restart the activity (if onDestroy called) , your problem could be inside the another class where you have the turn variable